# Sampling random numbers from beta distribution in numpy and assigning results to slice of pandas dataframe - SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to sample from a beta distribution using `numpy.random.beta` and assign the results to a slice of a dataframe, but I get a warning statement and then the values are not assigned.

My Python code:

`WINDSPEED_DATA` and `CHANCE_OF_LOSS` are pandas data frames.

`SAMPLE = int(round(WINDSPEED_DATA['COL_C'][0]*500))`

`SAMPLE`

OUTPUT = 36

`A = 100000*np.random.beta(WINDSPEED_DATA['ALPHA'][900], WINDSPEED_DATA['BETA'][900], SAMPLE)`

`A`

OUTPUT =
array([48208.9382933 , 49447.35371271, 51517.15876102, 49378.01557333,
53812.28691533, 50660.17268822, 46484.70198064, 52162.97995047,
59263.60202918, 46148.13163711, 50302.31063307, 56826.22553845,
49447.72447486, 56312.56912828, 54768.3425032 , 57623.95725306,
54514.62390499, 54758.8811204 , 46093.67015762, 40736.0878302 ,
57134.13807172, 51523.80130639, 46646.38621748, 42165.16519719,
54219.81212379, 45906.72074701, 47979.6811429 , 45766.47018937,
46903.99590919, 49661.3814001 , 49795.62562212, 51125.14533125,
56567.68884753, 55127.43209817, 45948.19643318, 47365.36720462])

`CHANCE_OF_LOSS[CHANCE_OF_LOSS.columns[0:SAMPLE]].iloc[900,:]`

OUTPUT =

Out[268]:
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4     0.0
5     0.0
6     0.0
7     0.0
8     0.0
9     0.0
10    0.0
11    0.0
12    0.0
13    0.0
14    0.0
15    0.0
16    0.0
17    0.0
18    0.0
19    0.0
20    0.0
21    0.0
22    0.0
23    0.0
24    0.0
25    0.0
26    0.0
27    0.0
28    0.0
29    0.0
30    0.0
31    0.0
32    0.0
33    0.0
34    0.0
35    0.0
Name: 900, dtype: float64

`len(A)`

OUTPUT = 36

`len(CHANCE_OF_LOSS[CHANCE_OF_LOSS.columns[0:SAMPLE]].iloc[900,:])`

OUTPUT = 36

`CHANCE_OF_LOSS[CHANCE_OF_LOSS.columns[0:SAMPLE]].iloc[900,:] = 100000*np.random.beta(WINDSPEED_DATA['ALPHA'][900], WINDSPEED_DATA['BETA'][900], SAMPLE)`

OUTPUT = **:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
CHANCE_OF_LOSS[CHANCE_OF_LOSS.columns[0:SAMPLE]].iloc[900,:] = 100000*np.random.beta(WINDSPEED_DATA['ALPHA'][900], WINDSPEED_DATA['BETA'][900], SAMPLE)**

When I try to assign the array of random samples from the beta distribution to the slice of the pandas data frame, I get the above error.

I am unable to assign the values to the data frame slice.

Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks for your time.

[The two data frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxlN6.png)

Comment: Can you print the columns of your DF? Are the first 'SAMPLE' number of columns reserved for the output of your random function?

Comment: I have included pictures of the two data frames in the edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following statement is using chained indexing. Hence you are unable to assign values.

```
CHANCE_OF_LOSS[CHANCE_OF_LOSS.columns[0:SAMPLE]].iloc[900,:] = 100000*np.random.beta(WINDSPEED_DATA['ALPHA'][900], WINDSPEED_DATA['BETA'][900], SAMPLE)
```

Instead, use `iloc` for selecting columns as well.

```
CHANCE_OF_LOSS.iloc[900,:SAMPLE] = 100000*np.random.beta(WINDSPEED_DATA['ALPHA'][900], WINDSPEED_DATA['BETA'][900], SAMPLE)
```

Comment: @ChiragSubramanian Your problem is solved. Now it would be nice to upvote or, better, accept the answer.

Comment: @Timus I'm unable to upvote it as I recently created an account on Stack Overflow and do not have a reputation score of 15 yet. However I do appreciate the answer.

Comment: @ChiragSubramanian I think you can upvote aswers to _your_ question? Most certainly you _accept_ them.

Comment: @ChiragSubramanian Okay, then what about _accepting_ (question from someone who's apparently dense): [As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)